# I need font with centered plus sign

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Hello I'm making the Add button for my iOS project. It has to use material style, so i've found BFPaperButton project on github. Now I need to find font where plus sign is vertically and horizontally centered. I've try many fonts, but not all. The most suitable is Times New Roman. Maybe someone now better font for my goal? I think if UIBarButton System items have their font - Add symbol has to be suitable, but I can't find it.

P.S.: Text in button centered
Here is an image of what I already have.
https://pp.vk.me/c622128/v622128875/1e805/D5K67mtyA50.jpg

And what I have to make
https://pp.vk.me/c622128/v622128875/1e80c/y0_W11kTl-0.jpg

P.P.S. I'm sorry for my English, I'm trying to write question without any translators.

Comment: Instead of different fonts, try different plus symbols: `+`, `˖`, `ᐩ`, `﹢`, `＋`, `➕`.

Comment: I've already tried from Special Character.

Comment: Or just use an image instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just used

> contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-12, 0, 0, 0);

It helped.